# Как после редиректа получить значение Location из заголовков ответа сервера python?

Tags: python, http, requests, redirect

Хочу сделать парсер сайта https://gdeposylka.ru/, но суть в том что при GET запросе в формате https://gdeposylka.ru/LD115373735CN сайт перенаправляет на

https://gdeposylka.ru/detect/LD115373735CN и только потом на

https://gdeposylka.ru/courier/china-ems/tracking/LQ263634861CN

при проверке истории перенаправлений показывает только первое перенаправление

вопрос в том как получить данные из заголовков ответов по запросу https://gdeposylka.ru/detect/LD115373735CN которые указаны на скрине а именно

**location: /courier/china-ems/tracking/LQ263634861CN**

```
import requests

url = "https://gdeposylka.ru/LD115373735CN"
auth = requests.get(url)
print(auth.headers)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

url = "https://gdeposylka.ru/LD115373735CN"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
                        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response1 = requests.head(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
response2 = requests.head(response1.headers['Location'], headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
print(response2.headers['Location'])
```

Вывод:

```
/courier/china-ems/tracking/LD115373735CN
```